# Why two TextView's from xml doesn't "saves" the same margin

Tags: android, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

I have a xml file, with 4 TextView's. When inflating the xml. I'm inflating the xml from different fragments, in some of the fragments i'm making **TextView2** visibility to *GONE*. The issue is : in fragments that i'm setting *TextView2* to *GONE*, the space between **TextView3** and **TextView4** is **smaller** than the gap between these two *TextView's* when *TextView2* visibility is *Visible* (although **TextView4** start is constraint to **TextView3**). Can someone explain me the reason to this behaviour and also suggest me a comfortable solution?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:dropDownWidth="120dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:dropDownVerticalOffset="96dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tempButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/spinner"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        tools:text="Button"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />


    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="13dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tempButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textColor="@color/titleTextColor"
        tools:text="TextView1" />


    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="13dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tempButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textColor="@color/titleTextColor"
        android:text="Symbol"
        tools:text="TextView2"/>



    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="13dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tempButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        app:layout_goneMarginStart="65dp"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textColor="@color/titleTextColor"
        tools:text="TextView3" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="13dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tempButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textColor="@color/titleTextColor"
        tools:text="TextView4" />




    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try to look into `layout_goneMargin`

Comment: @grig, I thought about it, but as i understand (please correct me if i wrong), it's only affects on the space between **TextView3** starts to the end of **TextView1/2**, it shouldn't affect the space between **TextView4** and **TextView3** end.

Comment: @DorVak , please read my answer.

Comment: @Septimiu, Thanks i read, but my question still exist. Please don't be angry, but i can't understand how to space between **TextView3** to to it's left can affect the space between **TextView4** and **TextView3**?

Comment: @Septimiu, setting to INVISIBLE doesn't fix the issue

Comment: @DorVak, I'm sorry but i can't reproduce your problem. It works fine, tv3 and tv4 are shifting to the left but the gap between is the same...

Comment: @Septimiu, this works only after you set it to *Invisible*? i must say that the difference in the gap seems to be much bigger than 6dp

Comment: @DorVak, if you set it to Invisible nothing should change, because the view is still there but it's not visible. When you set tv.visibility to Gone, then the views shift to the left, but the space between tv3 and tv4 remain the same, at least on my test, so i can't help you more than what i've already said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `textView2` has :

```
android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
```

so when you set visibility to `GONE`, those margins are gone as well. Try with `INVISIBLE` instead, if you want to keep the margins!